# Iterating functions of expectations

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation

We all know that $E[E[X]]=E[X]$. I was wondering, does it also hold that $E[g(E[X])]=E[g(X)]$ for "any" function $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example take a normal distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$ $X \simeq \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $g(x)=x^2$. You have $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=1$ and $\mathbb{E}(0^2)=0$.

However you can indeed say something interesting when $g$ is convex. In that case [Jensen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) inequality tells us that
$$ g(\mathbb{E}[X]) \leq \mathbb{E}[g(X)] $$

Take $-g$ for the concave case. When $g$ is affine, it is in particular convex and concave so your equality holds for any random variable $X$. Also $\mathbb{E}[g(\mathbb{E}[X])]=g(\mathbb{E}[X])$ since $g(\mathbb{E}[X])$ is a real number, not a random variable.

Comment: Being convex and concave is **not** equivalent to being constant.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This does not hold in general. Take any function $g$. Then 
$$
E[g(E[X])]=g(E[X]),
$$
since $g(E[X])$ is a constant. (By linearity of the expectation.)

In general if $g$ is measurable and integrable, $E[g(X)]\neq g(E[X])$. For example, if $g$ is convex or concave, then there is equality if and only if $g$ is linear or $X$ is constant. (This is the case of equality in [Jensen's inequaity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)).